# What does ^ mean in C++?

Tags: c++-cli

So I've just stumbled over this function in the WinApi

```
public:
static array<Process^>^ GetProcessesByName(
    String^ processName
)
```

What do the `^` stand for? Seems odd never seen this before.

Comment: This is managed C++, called CLI from microsoft and this is an garbage controlled pointer.

Comment: This isn't C++, rather C++/CLI or C++/CX.

Comment: That's not C++, it's C++/CLI. I believe `^` stands for something like "managed reference" there.

Comment: @Samuel, Managed C++ came before C++/CLI :)

Comment: "Cpp" does not stand for C++ anyway.

Comment: Also note: 'Cpp' is normally used to refer to the c preprocessor, not c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is C++/CLI, and `^` is for references (which are allocated with `gcnew`). References are garbage collected.

[.NET Programming in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx)

In this specific example, the function takes a reference to a string, and returns a reference to an array of references to `Process`. For anything that is a reference type, you *must* use `^` (in other words, you can't have a non-reference variable of that type).

As pointed out in a comment, this may instead be [C++/CX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699871.aspx), but the syntax is mostly the same, but uses `ref new` instead of `gcnew`.

[Visual C++ Language Reference (C++/CX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699871.aspx)

Comment: it also may be C++/CX

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, in your example `^` stands for Microsoft's C++/CLI garbage controlled pointers.

However, in standard C++ `^` is **the bitwise exclusive OR operator^**.

`operator^`compares each bit of its first operand to the corresponding bit of its second operand. If one bit is 0 and the other bit is 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = 0x5555;
  int b = 0xFFFF;
  std::cout  << std::hex << ( a ^ b ) << std::endl;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f386137d5cecd4a3)**

Comment: that I know ofc :) but it got me confused at the position.